# React: how to reverse a table from an api call

Tags: reactjs, datatables, axios

Im calling an api and this is what I get:

[image]

I want to be able to display this as a table being each one of these indexes a column. So my ideal result would be a table that looks like this:

| # | Score | LCP | FCP | SI | .. | .. | TTB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.25 | 3.7 | 7.9 | 14 | .. | .. | 0.65 |
| 2 | 0.23 | 3.7 | 7 | 11.4 | .. | .. |  |
| 3 | 0.20 | 4.3 | 6.4 | 9.4 | .. | .. |  |
| 4 | 0.22 | 3.9 | 7.1 | 11.6 | .. | .. |  |

Currently I am able to display the values in the dom but they look like this:
[image]

So it looks like my table is transposed. I want to how to revert it so that instead of showing the values of each index as lines it will be as columns

This is my code to display data in the dom:

```js
render() {

const { urls = []} = this.state

....

{urls.length > 0 ? (
  <Table hover>
  <tr>
          <th>Test #</th>
          <th>Score</th>
          <th>FCP</th>
          <th>SI</th>
          <th>LCP</th>
          <th>TTI</th>
          <th>TBT</th>
          <th>CLS</th>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
          {urls.map((kwsVal) => (
              <tr>
                  {Object.values(kwsVal).map((val) => (
                      <td>{val}</td>
                  ))}
              </tr>
          ))}
      </tbody>
  </Table>
) : <div>No data available</div>}
```

Comment: Is your initial data a dictionary (eg first key is 0, value is `{0: 0.25, 1: 0.23, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.2266666667}`) or is it an array (eg first element is `{0: 0.25, 1: 0.23, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.2266666667}`)?

Comment: Are you just asking how to render the rows as columns, and columns as rows?

Comment: @jnpdx I updated the json info with an image of the console and what im getting

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I dont think so. I want to render my data as columns and not rows. But im getting each index as rows. So for example {0: 0.25, 1: 0.23, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.2266666667} it would be a  column on the table and so on with the other results.

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose your data by doing this:

```
let content = [{0: 0.25, 1: 0.23, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.2266666667},
{0: 3.7, 1: 3.7, 2: 4.3, 3: 3.9},
{0: 7.9, 1: 7, 2: 6.4, 3: 7.1},
{0: 14, 1: 11.4, 2: 9.4, 3: 11.6},
{0: 16.2, 1: 16.6, 2: 16.6, 3: 16.4666666667},
{0: 820, 1: 1090, 2: 1440, 3: 1116.6666666667},
{0: 0.065, 1: 0.065, 2: 0.065, 3: 0.065}]

let rows = content.map((_,index) => {
    let columnValues = content.map(i => content[index][i])
  return columnValues
})

console.log(rows)
```